# IF statement seems to have an issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have the following IF condition in one of my programs, I set the condition to validate whether the mandatory text fields are empty, if so, to display an Error message, But even when the mandatory fields are empty still the records being saved regardless of mandatory fields.

```
if (!txt_teacherid.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherid.Equals("") && !txt_teacherfname.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherfname.Equals("") && !txt_teacherlname.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherlname.Equals("") && !txt_teacherdob.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherdob.Equals("") && !txt_teachernationality.Equals(null) && !txt_teachernationality.Equals("") && !txt_teacheraddress.Equals(null) && !txt_teacheraddress.Equals(""))
{
    String teacherid = txt_teacherid.Text.Trim();
    String teacherfname = txt_teacherfname.Text.Trim();
    String teacherlname = txt_teacherlname.Text.Trim();
    String teachergender = opt_gender.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    String teachercivilstatus = opt_civilstatus.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    String teacherdob = txt_teacherdob.Text.Trim();
    String teachernationality = txt_teachernationality.Text.Trim();
    String teacheraddress = txt_teacheraddress.Text.Trim();
    String teachercontactno = txt_teachercontactno.Text.Trim();
    String teacherqualification = txt_teacherqualification.Text.Trim();
    String teacherexperience = txt_teacherexperience.Text.Trim();
    String teacherjobtitle = txt_teacherjobtitle.Text.Trim();
    String teacherjoindate = txt_teacherjoindate.Text.Trim();
    String imgpath = (String)Session["imagepath"];

    DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
    db.getConnection();
    db.executeUpdateQuery("INSERT INTO Teacher (TeacherID,TeacherFirstName,TeacherLastName,TeacherGender,TeacherDOB,TeacherCivilStatus,TeacherNationality,TeacherQualification,TeacherExperience,TeacherJobTitle,TeacherAddress,TeacherContactNo,TeacherJoinDate,ImagePath) VALUES ('" + teacherid + "','" + teacherfname + "','" + teacherlname + "','" + teachergender + "','" + teacherdob + "','" + teachercivilstatus + "','" + teachernationality + "','" + teacherqualification + "','" + teacherexperience + "','" + teacherjobtitle + "','" + teacheraddress + "','" + teachercontactno + "','" + teacherjoindate + "','" + imgpath + "')");
    Session["imagepath"] = null;
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "recordInserted();window.location.href='AdminRegisterTeacher.aspx'", true);
    //Response.Redirect("AdminRegisterTeacher.aspx");
}
else 
{
    InnerError ie = new InnerError();
    ie.throwError("Oops! There was an error, Make sure you have filled all mandatory data");
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. Additionally, don't use the `""` literal, use `string.Empty`.

Comment: ... you are checking against `txt_teacherid` and not `txt_teacherid.Text` in the if statement.

Comment: Also, it appears that you're building your update statement dynamically.  You may want to consider using Parameters to minimize the risk of SQL Injection.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I believe thats checking if the control is initialised before reading its value.

Comment: @Jodrell why would the control not be there? If he's dynamically adding them and `txt_teacherid` is actually a local variable and not the actual control, then I would assume that would be in his post.

Comment: @Jodrell No, I think MikeSmithDev is right... That condition will always return true. The real issue is that the .Text property of the control should be checked for null, not the control itself.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, Well, its concievable that a variable holding a refernce to a control may not be initialised. Given the style of the rest of the code I'd assume nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (!txt_teacherid.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherid.Equals("")...` is wrong as your are checking against the *control* `txt_teacherid` and not the *text*.

it should simply be

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teacherid.Text.Trim())... )
```

or use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (.Net 4 and up):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_teacherid.Text) && ... )
```

And also note you should use parameterized queries to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: I believe thats checking if the control is initialised before reading its value

Comment: @Jodrell possible but not likely as he is also checking `txt_teacherid.Equals("")`.

Comment: @Jodrell The intent of the code and the question looks to be checking the _value_ of the control to see if a required field has been left empty. If so, the check is being done wrong and this is the answer that will give the right result. Besides, there's no need to check if the control is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You should use one of the following:

- string.IsNullOrEmpty()
- string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()

Answer (score 1):

String has method which is .IsNullOrEmpty() which will return a boolean. Have you tried using that instead?

So would be:

```
if (!txt_teacherid.IsNullOrEmpty() && !txt_teacherfname.IsNullOrEmpty()&& !txt_teacherlname..IsNullOrEmpty() && !txt_teacherdob.IsNullOrEmpty() && !txt_teachernationality.IsNullOrEmpty() && !txt_teacheraddress.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    //do database stuff here
}
```

Comment: I cannot find a such a method in my suggestions list in VS2010

Comment: Yeah sorry I have got it wrong, it's a static method so would be String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teacherid)...etc

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teacherid) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teacherfname) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teacherlname) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teacherdob) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teachernationality) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_teacheraddress))
{
  \\Save Data
}
else
{
  \\show error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
if (!txt_teacherid.Text.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherid.Text.Equals("") && !txt_teacherfname.Text.Equals(null) &&   !txt_teacherfname.Text.Equals("") && !txt_teacherlname.Text.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherlname.Text.Equals("") && !txt_teacherdob.Text.Equals(null) && !txt_teacherdob.Text.Equals("") && !txt_teachernationality.Text.Equals(null) && !txt_teachernationality.Text.Equals("") && !txt_teacheraddress.Text.Equals(null) && !txt_teacheraddress.Text.Equals(""))
```

In place of your existing condition